# Connect Excel Power Query to Power BI datasets?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way to connect to power bi services workspace/dataset via excel power query?

Excel can connect via Get Data>>>From Power platform but is there a way to connect via excel power query?

There is a power platform section in power query but not to the power bi platform, is there an add-in or driver that can be installed to make the connection available?

There is an old process that connects to an azure DB which needs to be replaced and hoping to find a way to connect to PBI dataset rather than rebuild the whole process?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the Power BI is published to the service, use **Data > Get Data > From Power Platform > From Power BI**.

[image]

Comment: Hi TheRizza, Power BI is published to the service and can be accessed via your example (Get Data), but the same option isn't available when you launch Power Query Editor, Is there another add-on or service that needs to be installed specifically for power query?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Power Query to get data from published Power BI datasets.

You can connect to the dataset, or you need an entry point further upstream, such as in a dataflow, to connect to the tabular data for further processing in Power Query.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I think you're right, I don't believe there is a way to connect to a dataset and then build out in the normal way you would in excel via pivot. I have managed to find a way to connect to a PBI dataset in power query and add in some dax to produce a tabular dataset which can then be filter in power query via OLE DB

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since your question and eventually you've already found a solution.

If not,You can create the connection following the steps below:

(#1) Create a connection to PBI from the workbook. Some options to do that: (#a) Data > Get Data > From Power platform > From Power BI; (#b) Data > Get Data > From Power Platform > From Power BI; (#c) Insert > PivotTable > From Power BI;

(#2) Copy the generated connection string: Data > Queries & Connections > Connections > Properties > Definition > Connection string

(#3) And finally, in the "Power Query" view: Create a new OLE DB type query, with the copied connection string.

**As a note:** You must remove the attributes "Integrated Security" and "Persist Security Info" from the copied connection string or it will be considered invalid.